# Javascript for loop compare with input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I am a Frontend Developer and weak in javascript. I need something different using "for loop". So I badly need help if anybody willing to. The thing is we normally compare the variable with a certain value or length but I want to compare here with a value from input field.

```
for($x = 1; $x < 5; $x++){
  //code goes here
}
```

I need to change this value '5' and instead of it I want to put value from Frontend input field so that I can manipulate with my desired value. Sorry if I can't express properly and Thanks in advance for assistance.

Comment: post the code of your input field please

Comment: Variables don't normally have `$` in Javascript. Is this perhaps PHP?

Comment: Hi Seva! here is the front end input field codes...
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Desired Row</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please type how many rows you want">
   </div>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRow()" <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> Add Row </button>

Comment: Yes this javascript codes are typed inside php tag #uom

Comment: so are you storing the value of the text input anywhere? maybe this happens in the addRow function? if so, you can change the 5 to the name of that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to compare each individual char in a string whose length you do not know until runtime, is that correct? You should just be able to use .length

```
var inputstring = "somestring"

for($x = 1; $x < inputstring.length; $x++){
  //code goes here
}
```

Comment: Yape Dudesgotagun u got it. That's the simplest way...I should have known earlier. Anyways thanks very much for quick response everybody.

Answer (score 0):

```
// YOUR PHP CODE
if ( isset($_POST['num']) && ctype_digit($_POST['num']) ) {
    $userInput = $_POST['num'];
} else {
    $userInput = '';
}

for ($x=1; $x < $userInput; $x++) {
    // Code goes here
}



// YOUR HTML CODE
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="num" />
        <input type="submit" value="Enter Number" />
    </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: The php code takes the user's input value, validates it by insuring it is a number, the finally stores the value inside a variable to use inside the for-loop.